# Compare previous row's date in grouped query

Tags: mysql, sql

I calculate hours that the air temperature below 7.22. I want to do this calculation on the SQL side.

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE datas (
  id INT,
  air_temperature DOUBLE(8,2),
  created_at TIMESTAMP
);

INSERT INTO datas (id, air_temperature, created_at) VALUES (1, 6.50, '2020-12-01 23:45:02');
INSERT INTO datas (id, air_temperature, created_at) VALUES (2, 6.50, '2020-12-02 03:45:02');
INSERT INTO datas (id, air_temperature, created_at) VALUES (3, 6.92, '2020-12-02 04:00:02');
INSERT INTO datas (id, air_temperature, created_at) VALUES (4, 6.99, '2020-12-02 04:15:02');
INSERT INTO datas (id, air_temperature, created_at) VALUES (5, 7.45, '2020-12-02 04:30:02');
INSERT INTO datas (id, air_temperature, created_at) VALUES (6, 7.34, '2020-12-02 04:45:02');
INSERT INTO datas (id, air_temperature, created_at) VALUES (7, 7.10, '2020-12-02 05:00:02');
INSERT INTO datas (id, air_temperature, created_at) VALUES (8, 7.00, '2020-12-02 05:20:02');
INSERT INTO datas (id, air_temperature, created_at) VALUES (9, 7.12, '2020-12-02 07:15:02');
```

Data's date interval can be anything.

**What I want to get**

```
date            ch
2020-12-01      1
2020-12-02      3.083
2020-12-03      {calculatedValue}
2020-12-04      {calculatedValue}
```

**Rules**

- if there isn't a previous row, we take this as 1 hour.
- if there is; we take the difference of two dates. BUT if it's higher
  than 1 hour, we take this as 1 hour.

**How 2020-12-02's value is 3.083?**

```
rowId 2 = take ch as 60 minutes (there's no previous row to compare, so take as 60 minutes. related to rule-1).
rowId 3 = take ch as 15 minutes. (the difference between the date of previous data and the date of current data)
rowId 4 = take ch as 15 minutes (same as rowId 3)
rowId 5 = take ch as 0 (it's not below 7.22)
rowId 6 = take ch as 0 (it's not below 7.22)
rowId 7 = take ch as 15 minutes (same as rowId 3)
rowId 8 = take ch as 20 minutes (same as rowId 3)
rowId 9 = take ch as 60 minutes (previous date is higher than 60 minutes. so take as 60 minutes. related to rule-2)

total minutes of day / 60 = 185 / 60 = 3.083 hours
```

If I get the previous value's date, I can compare and calculate but I don't know how can I get previous row while using group by.

I thought something like this but I am not sure how can apply rules above.

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%d-%m-%Y') as `date`,
    SUM((CASE WHEN air_temperature < 7.22 THEN (apply second rule here) ELSE 0 END)) as ch
FROM datas
GROUP BY `date`
```

EDIT: [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pxJ5JJRtDWWUqs9GWkbDJc/3)

Comment: What is you MySQL version?  because 8.0 has [LEAD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lead)

Comment: @Luuk it’s 8, I can use these functions

Comment: Give it a try, and show what you can accomplish with it. (Then we will know where your real problem is)

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: It is no clear when `ch 0.15` or `ch 0.20`  also you did not provide details about how this value `3.05` in you example is calculated, and it is not clear from the example where it is coming from...  Also table structure, (and table name!) and some sample data with desired output would help a lot in solving your problem. But SO is not about solving your problem, it is to help YOU solve your own problem.

Comment: @Strawberry sorry, I missed it. I added dbfiddle, is it enough?.

Comment: @Luuk you're right. I tried to clarify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LEAD()` to get the next `created_at`.  Then use arithmetic to limit the difference to 60:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%d-%m-%Y') as `date`,
       SUM( COALESCE(LEAST(TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, created_at, next_created_at), 60)), 60) / 60 as hours
FROM (SELECT d.*,
             LEAD(created_at) OVER (ORDER BY created_at) as next_created_at
      FROM datas d
     ) d
WHERE air_temperature < 7.22
GROUP BY `date`
```

Comment: You output is `2.0833`, desired output is `3.0833`. Who can explain the difference?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I added new data for `2020-12-01 23:45:02`. Now, it calculates 2020-12-02 correctly. but 2020-12-01 gets null, it must be equal to 1 because there's no previous row to compare. so take as 60 minutes (rule-1). how we can do this?

Comment: @akcoban . . . `COALESCE()`should do the right thing for that case.